# Mysql full lock on big import

Tags: mysql, database, mysqlimport, database-locking

I've one MYSQL server with 5 databases.

I was using phpmyadmin csv import to load a very big amount of data in one table of one database.

I understand that all other operations in this machine may get slower due to the amount of processing take, but MYSQL is simple not responding to any other simultaneous request, even in other table or in other database.

And because of this apache doen't answer any request that need database connection (keeps loading forever)

after the import is finished, the apache and the mysql return to work normaly... i dont need to restart or execute any other command

my question is, Is this behavior normal? should mysql stop answering all other requests due a single giant one?

I'm afraid that if i've a big query running in one database in this server, all my other databases will be locked also and my applications stop working

Comment: Impossible to say. It shouldn't but obvioulsy it can. It could be your machine is underpowered, and you have a high load. It could be a lot of things. If you really do suspect mysql locking, you can go into a console and check your `show processlist`. But if you don't have any specific suspicion of mysql itself then I'd suggest you look into the servers performance first. Memory, load, etc.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I really checked that mysql is locking... Apache handles any request that doesn't look on mysql normaly and i'm able to run other programs in my machine normally... my question is: "is this lock normal or i have a missconfiguration in my mysql server?"

Comment: how did you check? what is "mysql is locking" in this case? do you have a table-lock, or do you mean you can't open phpmyadmin in your browser? Most of the time there is a connection left for the console, try that if you can. Can you connect from a mysql-commandline?

Comment: I cant open phpmyadmin home page, and all others php pages that query database are loading forever... pages that not look on database load normally. i can connect from commandline and when i run show processlist it shows one single insert

Comment: If you have one running connection from your browser, it is expected you can not op en different pages and keep connecting -> check if it's not only blocking for you / for that browser. open a page on your mobile: does that still work?